# Java compare two string lists for specific characters and delete it

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two `String` lists.

**List-1 Ex.:** `"ftzat955","zat75" "a875rt955", "rRat955", "duozf", "ulw7trRT"`

**List-2 Ex.:** `"rt", "zf"`

Now I want to loop the first `List` and delete all the `String` that contain `"rt"` and `"zf"` from List-2.

I am not searching against a complete string instead I'm only searching for a string-pair in whole strings.

I didn't find any `Utils` that I can use to solve this problem.

Can somebody help me with this?

Thank you for helps.

Comment: Java String class has the method `contains()`
Just call it at you String Object and insert in the brakets the part String that  your String should contain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String l1 : list1)
{ 
    boolean stay = true;
    for (String l2 : list2)
           if (l1.contains(l1))
               stay = false;
    if (stay)
       resultList.add(l1);

}
```

Comment: Thank you i have used StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(l1, l2) instead of l1.contains(l2)

Answer (score 1):

```
public ArrayList<String> filterList(ArrayList<String> mainList, ArrayList<String> comparableList){
ArrayList<String> filteredList=new ArrayList<String>();
            for(String s: comparableList){
                for (String s2:mainList){
                    if(s2.contains(s))filteredList.add(s2);
                }
            }
            return filteredList;
        }
```